# PHP form to run Google Text-to-Speech script on server

Tags: php, html, exec

I want to run this via PHP `exec`:

```
./text2speech.sh "My name is Oscar and I am testing the audio."
```

Below is my code. How can I send the `""` without interfering with PHP?

```php
<?php

function doSomething($command) {
    exec("./text2speech.sh". " $command", $output);
    echo "Returned output:";
    var_dump($output);
} 

if(count($_POST) > 0 && isset($_POST['command'])) {
    doSomething($_POST['command']); 
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">

<title>Terminal Emulator</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <input autocomplete="off" id="command" name="command" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think he asks for sending commend and executing `text2speech` without php at all

Answer (score 0):

Have tried:

```
...
$call = "./text2speech.sh" . "\"" . $command . "\"";
exec($call, $output);
...
```

or all on one line

```
exec("./text2speech.sh \"$command\"", $output);
```

Haven't tried this, but `$call` shoud be equal './text2speech.sh "command text here" '

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to escape the quotes:

```
exec("./text2speech.sh \"$command\"", $output);
```

or use single outer quotes instead:

```
exec('./text2speech.sh "' . $command . '"', $output);
```

By the way, it's better to put the PHP code into the `<body>` section if you want to show the output.